# monitor url response time apache access log by zabbix

Tags: zabbix

use zabbix version 5.0.2.

server centos 7

i would httpd access log and analysis response time for special url !

Is it possible to calculate the server response time to a request from the network card to the user?

Comment: Please format you post. `tanks` how are "tanks" related? `to calculate` "Calculate"? I think you mean to _measure_ the response time, otherwise how would you _calculate_ it?

Comment: @KamilCuk ok, how to log response time url api my app on apache2 in zabbix?

Comment: You should start from the documentation: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual - try with log monitoring, web scenarios or http agent item

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni
tanks. i'm monitor url regex apache-agent?